# Как избавиться от Using temporary?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавится от Using temporary и что бы запрос работал максимально быстро при этом

Таблица категорий:

```
 `product_category_multi` (
      `m_Id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
      `prod_Id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `multi_cat` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Индексы:

```
ALTER TABLE `product_category_multi`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`m_Id`),
  ADD KEY `multi_cat` (`multi_cat`),
  ADD KEY `Id` (`prod_Id`);
```

вид внутри:

```
m_Id    prod_Id     multi_cat
-------+-----------+---------+  
1       1           5
2       1           1
3       1           6
4       2           5
5       2           1
6       3           5
7       4           5
8       4           6
```

Таблицы с товарами:

```
`shop_product` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_article` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_article_main` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_active` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_warehouse_temp` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `product_top` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;
```

Индексы:

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  ADD KEY `product_name` (`product_name`),
  ADD KEY `product_price` (`product_price`),
  ADD KEY `product_article_main` (`product_article_main`);
```

Вид внутри:

```
Id  product_article     product_article_main    product_category    product_name    product_price   product_active  product_warehouse_temp  product_top         
--+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+------------------------+------------+
1   qwe                 qwe                     5                   name1           20              1               1                       0
2   asd                 qwe                     5                   name2           30              1               1                       0
3   zxc                 qwe                     5                   name3           50              1               0                       1
4   wer                 sdf                     6                   name4           10              1               1                       0
5   sdf                 sdf                     6                   name5           20              1               1                       0
6   xcv                 sdf                     6                   name6           50              1               1                       0
7   ert                 cvb                     1                   name7           10              1               0                       1
8   cvb                 cvb                     1                   name8           20              1               1                       0
```

1 вариант запроса с Using temporary:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
(
    SELECT prod.Id
    FROM shop_product prod
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT prod_Id
            FROM product_category_multi
            WHERE multi_cat = '5'
        ) AS cat ON cat.prod_Id = prod.Id

    WHERE 
        prod.product_active = '1' 
        AND prod.product_published_start <= 1471376797
        AND prod.product_price = (
            select MIN(temp.product_price)
            from shop_product temp 
            where prod.product_article_main=temp.product_article_main 
        )   
    ORDER BY prod.product_warehouse_temp DESC, prod.product_top DESC, prod.product_review DESC, prod.Id ASC
    LIMIT 0, 20
) B 
INNER JOIN shop_product A USING (Id)
```

Showing rows 0 - 19 (20 total, Query took 0.0899 seconds.)

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type     table                   type        possible_keys           key                     key_len     ref                             rows    Extra
--+---------------+------------------------+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>              ALL         NULL                    NULL                    NULL        NULL                            20      
1   PRIMARY         A                       eq_ref      PRIMARY                 PRIMARY                 4           B.Id                            1           
2   DERIVED         product_category_multi  ref         multi_cat,Id            multi_cat               3           const                           6869    Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED         prod                    eq_ref      PRIMARY                 PRIMARY                 4           product_category_multi.prod_Id  1       Using index condition; Using where
4   DEP. SUBQUERY   temp                    ref         product_article_main    product_article_main    62          prod.product_article_main       3
```

Вариант 2, работает быстро, без Using temporary но не отрабатывает ORDER BY

```
        SELECT B.*
            FROM(
                SELECT prod_Id
                FROM product_category_multi
                WHERE multi_cat = '5'
            ) cat

            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    prod.Id
                FROM shop_product prod
                WHERE 
                    prod.product_price = (
                        select MIN(temp.product_price)
                        from shop_product temp 
                        where prod.product_article_main=temp.product_article_main 
                    )
                    AND prod.product_active = '1' 
                    AND prod.product_published_start <= '1471268208'
                ORDER BY 
                    prod.product_warehouse_temp DESC, prod.product_top DESC
            ) prod ON cat.prod_Id = prod.id


        INNER JOIN shop_product B USING (Id)
```

Showing rows 0 - 24 (2296 total, Query took 0.0046 seconds.)

Comment: А почему у вас `ORDER BY` во вложенных запросах, а не во внешнем запросе?

Comment: @cheops Во втором варианты да, но он и не работает. В первом варианте ORDER BY  во внешнем запросе, но дает Using temporary

Comment: Дался вам этот using temporary. у вас подзапрос select min() выполняется 6 тысяч раз. И вас это не напрягает ? меня бы напрягло и я бы подумал о каком нибудь join с подзапросом возвращающим за один проход все необходимые минимумы. хотя конечно по общему количеству записей в таблице надо смотреть.